# Intersecting intervals probability puzzle

Tags: probability

I’m working on the following probability puzzle:

> Intersecting Intervals
>
> Choose two random numbers from $[0, 1]$ and let them be the endpoints of a random interval. Repeat this n times. What
> is the probability that there is an interval which intersects all
> others

I reason that the solution is $\frac 1 {n^2}$ with the following reasoning:

Say we draw uniform random variables $\sim (0,1)$ in pairs of two, calling the first of the pair $L_i$ and the second $R_i$ with $i$ from $1$ to $n$ (we draw $n$ of these pairs).

The probability that any interval intersects all others is the probability that that interval’s left bound is smaller than all other intervals’ left bound and its right bound greater than all other intervals’ right bound.

Because these uniform random variables are i.i.d., by symmetry, the probability that any intervals left bound is smaller than all other left bounds is $\frac 1 n$. The probability that that intervals right bound is ALSO greater than all other right bounds equivalently $\frac 1 n$

Therefore the desired probability is $\frac 1 {n^2}$

I couldn’t find any solutions online so I would love for someone to point out any holes in my logic or confirm my solution. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to do this analytically either, but I can simulate it in Mathematica using its interval-arithmetic functionality. (I may document this as a CW answer when I get a chance.) Doing so, I seem to get the probabilities of common interval for $n=2,3,4,5$ as roughly $0.66,0.20, 0.228,0.127$. By contrast, the proposed analytical formula would give $0.25,0.11,0.0625,0.04$. So that seems to rule out said formula, assuming I'm correctly simulating the problem.

Comment: What you stated, left bound is minimum and right bound is maximum, defines an interval that *contains* all other intervals. An interval *intersects* all others if its left bound is less than all *right* bounds and its right bound is greater than all *left* bounds. For $n=2$ it is easy to see that the probability is $\frac{2}{3}$. Simulation shows a surprising result: the probability is the same for all $n$.

Comment: After some more exploration, the problem I simulated seems to have $2^n/\binom{2n}{n}$ for the probability for any common interval to survive. (This is based on OEIS sequence [AO55546](https://oeis.org/A055546).)

Comment: There is a neat solution to prove always p=(2/3) that works by placing 2n+1 points on a circle instead of a segment. When starting at some 0, move until you hit L1 for the second time, turn and move to second L2. You must have crossed 0 after turning, so the string includes a L1, a 0 and a L2. You can have 3 orders for these strings, two of which will refer to an interval that intersects all others, one refers to no such interval. Each string is equally likely, so p=(2/3).

Comment: Here is an attempt to clarify Piita's picture. Suppose we start with the segment [0,1] along with $2n$ distinct points, with half of these points labelled as $a$ and the rest as $b$. We can then deform this segment into a circle, with the endpoints $0,1$ having been collapsed into a single point labelled $X$. The claim is then that this picture is sufficient to determine whether a common interval exists for the original problem. (That said, I can't make sense of the $p=2/3$ conclusion claimed by others.)

Comment: It turns out this has been addressed over at CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148145/211265. Using the pictures there, I can clarify the difference between my results and the others. Let $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be some set of intervals in $[0,1]$. What I considered was whether $\cap_k I_k$ is non-empty and thus an interval. The p=2/3 result obtains by asking if, for all $j$, there exists $k$ such that $I_j \cap I_k\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @Semiclassical See my answer, which is actually a long-winded comment.

Comment: @DanielMathias See my answer, which is actually a long-winded comment.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not an answer**
This is a long-winded comment.

In the discussion below, I explain the intent behind the offered solution to this problem.  In the Addendum to this (long-winded) comment, I discuss a specific aspect to the solution that I consider $~\color{red}{\text{incomplete}}.$

---

I (also) was very confused by the language used in the solution posted [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/RandomIntervals.shtml).  Finally, after about an hour, after I experimented with different ways of interpreting the provided solution, I was able to make sense out the solution.

The easiest way to explain the ideas intended by the solution is with an illustration.  Instead of assuming that $~2n~$ random variables are involved, assume that the elements in the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,2n\}~$ are going to be randomly used to form $~n~$ pairs.  This means that the selection of each number will be done without replacement, so each number is used to form one of the pairs.

Note that when you (instead) select $~2n~$ random numbers from an interval, such as $~[0,1]~$ the probability that any two of the numbers are equal is $~0.~$ So, you can assume, without loss of generality, that $~2n~$ distinct numbers are involved.

---

For illustrative purposes, suppose that $~n = 3,~$ and the elements in $~\{1,2,\cdots,6\}~$ are used to form the pairs (i.e. intervals) $~[1,4], ~[2,3], ~[5,6].~$

Per the **intention** of the provided solution, one of the $~3~$ intervals will have its endpoints labeled [a,a], one of the intervals will have its endpoints labeled [b,b], and one of the intervals will have its endpoints labeled [c,c].

$\color{red}{\text{However, which labels will be assigned to which intervals ?}}$

---

Assume that the numbers $~0,1,2,3,4,5,6,~$ are placed in clockwise order, around a circle, with the number $~0~$ at the head of the circle.

So, if you were to traverse the numbers in a clockwise direction, starting at $~0,~$ and returning to $~0,~$ the first number that you would encounter would be $~1,~$ and the last number that you would encounter would be $~6.~$

Suppose that you make this clockwise traversal, but $~\color{red}{\text{stop}}~$ the first time that you come to the $~\color{red}{\text{start and stop}}~$ of an interval.

In the given example where the intervals are $~[1,4], ~[2,3], ~[5,6],~$ although the first endpoint that you encounter is from the interval $~[1,4],~$ the first interval where you encounter both the low and high endpoints is the interval $~[2,3].~$

Therefore, in the given solution, the interval $~[2,3]~$ is labeled [a,a].

Now, starting from the point $~3,~$ you reverse direction, and traverse **counter clockwise** until you encounter both the low and high endpoints of some interval.

Note that because of the algorithm used to identify $~[2,3]~$ as the interval [a,a], it will be impossible to encounter both points of a different interval, before you cross $~0.~$

So, traversing counterclockwise from the point $~3,~$
what happens is that you encounter one endpoint from the interval [1,4], namely the number $~1.$

Then, you continue to traverse counterclockwise, and you encounter the $~6~$ and then the $~5.~$  So, because of this, you label the interval $~[5,6]~$ as [b,b].

I emphasize, the interval $~[5,6]~$ becomes [b,b] specifically because during the counter clockwise traversal, from the number $~3,~$ the $~[5,6]~$ interval was the first interval where you encountered **both of the endpoints** of this interval.

---

At this point, while traversing counter clockwise, you have stopped at the number $~5.$

At this point, you are supposed to label the point $~0~$ as X.

Then, you are supposed to consider all of the endpoints labeled either a, b, or X, **strictly** between the $~5~$ and the $~3,~$ where this **consideration** is supposed to consider the numbers in a clockwise direction.

In a clockwise direction, the relevant numbers are $~6~$ which has been assigned the label b, $~0~$ which has been assigned the label X, and $~2,~$ which has been assigned the label a.

As the solution discusses, the three pertinent numbers, in order, in this consideration, for this particular formation of the three intervals, form the pattern

$\color{red}{\text{bXa}}.$

Further, the [b,b] interval does not intersect the [c,c] interval $~[1,4]~$ and in fact, among the three intervals $~[1,4], ~[2,3], ~[5,6],~$ there is no interval that intersects all of the other intervals.

---

**Addendum**

I completely agree with most of the analysis given in the offered solution, now that I am finally able to make sense out it.

That is, I agree that if you follow the labeling directions, you will encounter one of the following three patterns:

- bXa
- Xba
- Xab

I also agree that there will be some interval that intersects all of the other intervals, if and only if, the pattern encountered is either Xba or Xab.

The one portion of the analysis that I consider incomplete is that you are supposed to therefore conclude that the probability is $~(2/3)~$ that the random formation of $~n~$ intervals from the elements $~\{1,2,\cdots,2n\}~$ will result in some interval that intersects all of the other intervals.

The difficulty with this conclusion is that it assumes that the *patterns* bXa, Xba, Xab are equally likely.

That is, if you can prove that each of those three patterns are equally likely, then you have proven that the probability is in fact $~(2/3).$

However, I do not see any proof, in the analysis that the three patterns are equally likely.  This is why I consider the solution incomplete.

Comment: Well done!${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the unit interval, we drop $(2n+1)$ points on a circle. One, say $X$, is the starting point for traversing the circle. All other points are labeled in **successive** pairs a,b,….

By assumption, all cyclic orderings of $(2n)$ points are equally likely.

Given such point placement, start with X and move clockwise until you meet one symbol, say $a$, for the second time. Turn around, and move counterclockwise until you meet under symbol, say $b$, twice. Necessarily you have gone beyond X.

Now look at the string of symbols between the $b$ and the $a$ at the extremes of this trajectory, but running clockwise, from the (second) $b$ to the (second) $a$. This string includes X, the other $a$ and the other $b$. Look at the order in which these three ($X$, other $a$, other $b$) occur. There are just three possibilities:

Case (1): bXa
Case (2): Xba
Case (3): Xab

*Claim*
In cases 2) and 3), the interval $b$ intersects all others, whereas in case 1) there is no interval that intersects all others.

*Proof*
In cases (2) and (3), if $b$-interval does not intersect some $c$-interval, then the relevant symbols occur either as $bccXb$ or $bXccb$, contradicting the choices of either $b$ or $a$.

On the other hand, in case (1), if a $c$-interval intersects both the $b$-interval and the $a$-interval, then both $c$ symbols must lie in the string, contradicting the choice of $b$, since we had successive pairs. This completes the proof.

Since all distributions are equally likely, each of the cases (1) - (3) has probability of $\frac{1}{3}$, meaning that the existence of an interval that meets all other intervals is $\frac{2}{3}$, which is indeed independent of $n$.

Comment: I can't make sense of this. I think the problem lies with "successive pairs $a,b$": it is not at all clear to me what this means. Perhaps a couple of concrete examples would help.

Comment: @TonyK see my answer, which is actually a long-winded comment.  See especially, the Addendum at the end of my response, where I assert that the offered solution is incomplete.